# Conditional Formatting if all cells fail to meet a certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

[This is the spreadsheet I'm working on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FOZFd1Ra_L4wnI0yiss-R0zyGao6sU3S-a3UNZHPys/edit#gid=189198236). I am trying to figure out a formula for conditional formatting so that it only highlights the cells in red if none of the cells from columns N to Y of the Failed tab says either "Yes, I take this medication within the specified dosage range" or "I am unsure If I take this".

Comment: What column  should be highlighted in this case? All columns N-Y or something else?

Comment: columns N-Y should be highlighted; none if the condition is met

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After selecting the range N2:Y, apply to it conditional formatting with "Custom formula is:"

```
=sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch($N2:$Y2, "Yes, I take this medication within the specified dosage range|I am unsure If I take this")))) = 0
```

Explanation: `$N2:$Y2` refers to the range N-Y in the current row. `regexmatch($N2:$Y2, "this|that")` returns True when the cell contains either "this" or "that" (this is a substring search, which is appropriate in your case). Then `N` converts True to 1 and False to 0. The whole array of these 1-0 values is then summed, and the formatting applies if the sum is 0, meaning there were no matches.

Comment: Thanks @Bookend. The formula works on non-empty cells but the empty cells are formatted in red because they met the criteria too. How do I get around that?

Comment: You can exclude empty cells by changing the formula to =`len(N2)*(sum(...) = 0)` where sum(...) is as above